# How to change $(var.Platform) from x86 to Win32 in Wix

Tags: c++, wix, platform

I have a Visual C++ 2013 solution including many C++ projects and a WIX installer project.
On x64 platform, everything is okay.
But On x86 platform, $(OutDirectory)$(Platform)$(Configuration) of C++ projects is ...Win32..., but $(OutDirectory)$(Platform)$(Configuration) of WIX is ...x86...
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have all the projects added to your WiX project as references.  Lets say one of your C++ projects was called "MyHelperProject."  You can access that projects output binary like this:

```
<Component Guid="{723E4174-C9D2-4385-844E-C7D035B0C8FB}" Directory="INSTALL_ROOT">
    <File Source="$(var.MyHelperProject.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"/>   
</Component>
```

Or, if you want to grab other files from that build:

```
<Component Guid="{A0D64469-A90C-4DF3-A54B-B386AC49E6E7}" Directory="INSTALL_ROOT">
    <File Source="$(var.MyHelperProject.TargetDir)required_file.txt" KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>
```